# Python Unable to Find SQL Value From Database

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have been working with an SQL database through the mySQL library in Python. I have recently found that when I try searching for a string in my database, it is not correctly returning the output I expect. I think this may be due to my variable not being properly inserted into my SQL command.

```
code = data['code']
sql = "SELECT 200 FROM mytable WHERE mycolumn = '%s';"
query.execute(sql, teamCode)
print(str(query.fetchall()))
```

My problem is that printing query.fetchall() prints an empty list ([]) instead of the expected [[200,]] which means the program thinks the `code` value it is using does not exist in the SQL database, which it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameters in an `execute` call need to be a sequence, like a tuple.  Try:

```
query.excute(sql, (teamCode,))
```

That turns it into a one-element tuple.  BTW, did you really mean "code" there?